# ValueError: time-weighted interpolation only works on Series or DataFrames with a DatetimeIndex When using Pandas Interpolate using Time method

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling

I am using a dataset found on the Kaggle website (https://www.kaggle.com/claytonmiller/lbnl-automated-fault-detection-for-buildings-data) **specifically the 'RTU.CSV'**.

I have converted the timestamp to DateTime using following code:

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
```

yet when I try to use the **Pandas Interpolate using Time method**

```
df.interpolate(method = "time")
```

**The Error I get is**

> ValueError: time-weighted interpolation only works on Series or
> DataFrames with a DatetimeIndex

Can anyone explain what does this means?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call the interpolate on the whole dataframe instead of just the timestamp column. The dataframe has other columns that are not time data. The interpolate will work if: it is called on a specific `Series` (column) if it is time data, or the dataframe, via an index (`DatetimeIndex`).

I imagine this is what you intended to do:

```
df['Timestamp'].interpolate(method = "time")
```

If you wish to turn your timestamp column into the index:

```
df.set_index(df['Timestamp'], inplace=True)
```

*Edit from seeing the dataset:* my guess is that you might need something a bit more powerful than interpolate if you want to, basically, predict all columns values based on the timestamp and historical data. `iterpolate` is here more to fill the gaps in a column for example. As your timestamp is pretty regular, you can also choose to assume the rest of the data is partially independent from it and call interpolate on all columns 1 by 1 (the `method` might need to be changed). But since it is big chunks of data missing at the start, not sure how good `interpolate` guesses would be

Comment: Thanks for sharing your suggestion, I tried your code, however, this only selects the Timestamp column. I need to fill the NaN values using interpolations based on-time method for rest of the dataframe.

Comment: Can you explain the alternate way you mentioned: "the dataframe, via an index (DatetimeIndex)"?

Comment: @arash I am not too sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. From you dataset, the time column as no NaN, and the other columns are not time data (but temperatures)

Comment: @arash I updated the answer with how to replace the index. See if that helps

Comment: Let me explain; I may be using the wrong method here. So as you mentioned, I want to replace the NaN values in the columns with temperature using the interpolation method. Still, at the same time, I want to consider the dates when the linear interpolation is being calculated. i.e., the interpolation should consider the time when interpolating the float values of temperature. I hope I have sent the message on what I am trying to achieve here.

Comment: I tried your approach, but it did not work, and it only returned two timestamp columns next to each other. It does not perform the interpolation for the other columns.

Comment: @arash From seeing the data my guess is that you might need something a bit more powerful than interpolate if you want to, basically, predict all columns values based on the timestamp and historical data. `iterpolate` is here more to fill the gaps in a column for example. As your timestamp is pretty regular, you can also choose to assume the rest of the data is partially independent from it and call interpolate on all columns 1 by 1 (the method might need to be changed). But since it is big chunks of data missing at the start, not sure how helpful it would be

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I will work on it; I appreciate your help.